# SUM and JOIN 2 columns with different tables but it duplicates results

Tags: sql-server, join, query, sum

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code] AS [Loc Code]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Description]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Description 2]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Quantity] AS [QTY]
FROM [Transfer Shipment Line]
LEFT JOIN [Trans_ Sales Entry]
ON [Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code]=[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Store No_] AND
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]=[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Item No_] AND
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]=[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Variant Code]
WHERE
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code]='LOCATION1' AND
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]='ITEM01' AND
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]='VARIANT01'
```

Query result (correct quantity)

```
Loc Code   -   Item No_   -   Description   -   Description2   -   Variant Code   -   QTY
LOCATION1   ITEM01         ACTIVE            BLACK                VARIANT01          1
LOCATION1   ITEM01         ACTIVE            BLACK                 VARIANT01         2
```

SUM QUERY

```
SELECT DISTINCT
MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code]) AS [Loc Code]
,MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_])
,MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Description])
,MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Description 2])
,MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code])
,SUM([Transfer Shipment Line].[Quantity]) AS [QTY]
FROM [Transfer Shipment Line]
LEFT JOIN [Trans_ Sales Entry]
ON [Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code]=[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Store No_] AND
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]=[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Item No_] AND
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]=[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Variant Code]
WHERE
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code]='LOCATION1' AND
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]='ITEM01' AND
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]='VARIANT01'
GROUP BY
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]
```

Query result (with SUM)

```
Loc Code   -   Item No_   -   Description   -   Description2   -   Variant Code   -   QTY
LOCATION1   ITEM01         ACTIVE            BLACK                VARIANT01          9
```

If I remove the `DISTINCT` from 1<sup>st</sup> query, it duplicates the result also

```
Loc Code   -   Item No_   -   Description   -   Description2   -   Variant   -   QTY
LOCATION1   ITEM01         ACTIVE            BLACK                VARIANT01          2
LOCATION1   ITEM01         ACTIVE            BLACK                VARIANT01          2
LOCATION1   ITEM01         ACTIVE            BLACK                VARIANT01          2
LOCATION1   ITEM01         ACTIVE            BLACK                VARIANT01          1
LOCATION1   ITEM01         ACTIVE            BLACK                VARIANT01          1
LOCATION1   ITEM01         ACTIVE            BLACK                VARIANT01          1
```

---

Here's my revised SQL query code:

```
SELECT
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code] AS [Loc Code]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Description]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Description 2]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Quantity] AS [Transfer Order]
,[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Quantity] AS [Sales Entry]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Quantity]+[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Quantity] AS [Total]
FROM
(
SELECT
MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code])
,MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_])
,MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Description])
,MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Description 2])
,MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code])
,SUM([Transfer Shipment Line].[Quantity])
FROM [Transfer Shipment Line]
GROUP BY
[Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]
,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]
) AS TSL
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
MAX([Trans_ Sales Entry].[Store No_])
,MAX([Trans_ Sales Entry].[Item No_])
,MAX([Trans_ Sales Entry].[Variant Code])
,COALESCE(SUM(coalesce([Trans_ Sales Entry].[Quantity],0)),0)
FROM [Trans_ Sales Entry]
GROUP BY
[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Store No_]
,[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Item No_]
,[Trans_ Sales Entry].[Variant Code]
) AS TSE
ON
TSL.[Transfer-to Code] = TSE.[Store No_] AND
TSL.[Item No_] = TSE.[Item No_] AND
TSL.[Variant Code] = TSE.[Variant Code]
WHERE
TSL.[Transfer-to Code]='LOCATION1' AND
TSL.[Item No_]='ITEM01' AND
TSL.[Variant Code]='VARIANT01';
```

Answer (score 2):

You’re not using the joined table for anything. It’s not filtering because it’s an outer join, so it’s only there duplicating rows. So try this:

```
SELECT
    [Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code] AS [Loc Code]
    , [Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]
    ,MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Description])
    ,MAX([Transfer Shipment Line].[Description 2])
    ,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]
    ,SUM([Transfer Shipment Line].[Quantity]) AS [QTY]
FROM [Transfer Shipment Line]
WHERE [Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code]='LOCATION1' 
AND [Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]='ITEM01' 
AND [Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]='VARIANT01'
GROUP BY
  [Transfer Shipment Line].[Transfer-to Code]
 ,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Item No_]
 ,[Transfer Shipment Line].[Variant Code]
```

Edit: based on the rest of the info you’ve provided, do something like:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM 
(SELECT ... 
   FROM [Transfer Shipment Line] 
   GROUP BY ...
 ) tsl 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ... 
  FROM [Trans_ Sales Entry] 
  GROUP BY ...
) tse 
ON ...
```

Edit again:

```
SELECT    
TSL.[Transfer-to Code] AS [Loc Code]
,TSL.[Item No_]
,TSL.[Description]
,TSL.[Description 2]
,TSL.[Variant Code]
,TSL.[Transfer Order]
,TSE.[Sales Entry]
,TSL.[Transfer Order] + TSE.[Sales Entry] AS Total
FROM
(
SELECT
[Transfer-to Code]
,[Item No_]
,MAX([Description]) AS [Description]
,MAX([Description 2]) AS [Description 2]
,[Variant Code]
,SUM([Quantity]) AS [Transfer Order]
FROM
[Transfer Shipment Line]
GROUP BY
[Transfer-to Code]
,[Item No_]
,[Variant Code]
) AS TSL
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
[Store No_]
,[Item No_]
,[Variant Code]
,COALESCE(SUM([Quantity]),0) AS [Sales Entry]
FROM
[Trans_ Sales Entry]
GROUP BY
[Store No_]
,[Item No_]
,[Variant Code]
) AS TSE
ON 
TSL.[Transfer-to Code] = TSE.[Store No_]
AND TSL.[Item No_]  = TSE.[Item No_]
AND TSL .[Variant Code] = TSE.[Variant Code]
WHERE
TSL.[Transfer-to Code]='LOCATION1' AND
TSL.[Item No_]='ITEM01' AND
TSL.[Variant Code]='VARIANT01'
```

Comment: I had a rogue close-parens.

Comment: what do you mean by I had a rogue close-parens? thank you

Comment: I had a typo in my query. I had an extra “)”

Comment: sorry, but cant see where is the extra ")"  thank you

Comment: I edited the answer to remove it.